# Cannot open IIS 7.5 in Windows 7

Tags: iis-express

I am using Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010. I just downloaded and installed IIS 7.5 from www.microsoft.com . Installation also ended up successfully. But I cant able to find IIS in any of the way which I could find in the internet. I tried by Run -> inetmgr , control panel -> Administrative tools -> IIS . But I cannot find IIS anywhere. I also found an answer in stackoverflow forum for World Wide Web Publishing Service. but I cant find that too. Please help me. :(

Comment: Anyone there to get me out of this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. I made IIS enabled in control panel. There is an option in control panel as Turn Windows on/off. In that I checked all the sub folders under IIS menu. Now I can able to open the IIS manager. If any one come across this issue, u can try this step too.